# Mapping input and output sequences using neural networks in high dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, ai.artificial-intel

I have this huge dimensional data with 31200 features and only 6000 examples. I want to learn a neural network  that can find the non linear relation between the input and outputs. However, I have huge number of features. So wouldn't it cause problems in neural network?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Dimensionality Reduction Techniques like [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis).

There's [this](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/tutorials/dimred-survey.pdf) survey by Fodor, but it involves some math, so you can look into this [tutorial](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~aghodsib/courses/f06stat890/readings/tutorial_stat890.pdf) as well.

Another thing you can do is Feature Selection in the preprocessing step. You can look into [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/231175355_On_General_Definition_of_L1-norm_Support_Vector_Machines_for_Feature_Selection/file/79e415063b2049dc26.pdf) by Nguyen.

Also if you want an easy way out, you can use the [Software Package](http://featureselection.asu.edu/software.php) from ASU. They have a fairly well documented [report](http://featureselection.asu.edu/featureselection_techreport.pdf) on it as well.

Hope this somewhat helps.
Have fun Learning :)